# Change value from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to change a value from an array inside a multidimensional array, given a condition.

```
$arg_pub = array(
    'post_type' => 'pubs',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'pub_y',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'pub_y',
            'value' => array( $_period_from, $_period_to),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        ),
    ),      
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'index',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'class',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'author',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array('joe', 'peter', 'mark'), //array to be changed
        ),
    ),
);

if ( $some_condition ) {

    // I want to only replace the values from this specific array from the $arg_pub:
    // terms => array('joe', 'peter', 'mark')
    $arg_pub['tax_query'][...]['terms'] = array('susan', 'martha');
    // EDIT: with [...] I mean that I don't know what to write there.
    // The position for this array won't be always [2], it could change.

}
```

Is it necessary to do a foreach loop maybe?
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: loop through the array (by reference ) and just assign what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the ellipsis is doing, but have you tried :

```
$arg_pub['tax_query'][2]['terms'] = array('susan', 'martha');
```

===

UPDATE:

Would this work for you?

```
...
'tax_query' => array(
    'index' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'index',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array('one', 'two', 'three'),
    ),
    'class' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'class',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'),
    ),
    'author' => array(
        'taxonomy' => 'author',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array('joe', 'peter', 'mark'), //array to be changed
    ),
),
...

$arg_pub['tax_query']['author']['terms'] = array('susan', 'martha');
```

====

UPDATE 2:

Try this:

```
foreach($arg_pub['tax_query'] as &$taxq){
    if($taxq['taxonomy'] == 'author'){
        $taxq['terms'] = array('susan', 'martha');
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot use the [2], because sometimes it will be in another position. The valid reference is that the value for taxonomy should be 'author'...

Comment: Can you change it to use 'author' as the index instead?

Comment: Mmm... It should be WP syntax, and I guess that using 'author' it is not...

Comment: Not familiar with WordPress's syntax, just PHP.  I would say just loop that internal array.  Is it going to be short like that?  2-4 or so members?  If so, just loop it and test against 'taxonomy' for 'author'.

Comment: And if I want to alter the $arg_pub while doing the foreach? So after the foreach loop I can continue using the $arg_pub array...

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I posted code that updates that part of the array.  Give it a try.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try this:  `foreach($arg_pub['tax_query'] as &$taxq){`  The `&` means it's a reference.

Comment: It works, but to avoid a "warning" message, you need to check if the key is in array or not (through isset). Many thanks! And also note that the & is required.

Comment: The & makes it a reference, so that makes sense.  I believe you have to unset that variable after you're done with it, or something, look up "foreach" in the official documentation.  I'm not super familiar with PHP, mostly program Javascript and ASP.net.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the `...` with `2`:

```
$arg_pub = array(
    'post_type' => 'pubs',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'pub_y',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'pub_y',
            'value' => array( $_period_from, $_period_to),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        ),
    ),      
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'index',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array('one', 'two', 'three'),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'class',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'author',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => array('joe', 'peter', 'mark'), //array to be changed
        ),
    ),
);

if ( $some_condition ) {

    // I want to only replace the values from this specific array from the $arg_pub:
    // terms => array('joe', 'peter', 'mark')
    $arg_pub['tax_query'][...]['terms'] = array('susan', 'martha');

}
```